# Best Way to Resize Numpy Dtype for Structured data

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a good way to resize numpy structured dtypes without having to rebuild the entire dtype every time? I currently have a mechanism to do this, but I was curious if there is a more efficient way. To illustrate what I am asking, I have provided some code. The basic idea is that I want to resize the data type of a specific name.

```
def resize_dtype(orig_type, resized_type): 
    # I have a bunch of logic in here to loop and build new_array
    return new_dtype

def test_resize_dtype():
    type1 = np.dtype({'names':['col1', 'col2'], 'formats':['2i' ,'4i']})
    type2 = np.dtype({'names':['col', 'descr'], 'formats':[5*type1, 'S32']})

    tmp = np.dtype({'names':['col1', 'col2'], 'formats':['10i' ,'4i']})
    desired_type = np.dtype({'names':['col', 'descr'], 'formats':[5*tmp, 'S32']})
    resized_type = np.dtype([('col1', '10i')])
    new_type = resize_dtype(type2, resized_type)
    assert new_type == desired_type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not fair.  You show the testing framework, but none of the code that actually does the sizing.  On first glance `test_resize_dtype` looks like it focused on modifying the `np.dtype` objects.  But after defining a bunch of `dtypes`, all it does is call an unknown `resize_array` - or is that a typo, and you really mean to call the nearly as unknown `resize_dtype` function?

But I duduce that your main goal here is to change the internal array size of a nested dtype, `col1`, from `(4,)` to `(10,)`.

As far as I know there isn't a neat or efficienct way of changing such an array.  You are just going to have to make a new array with the new dtype, and copy data, field by field, from old to new, with adjustments for shape as needed.

`X.dtype` defines how numpy views each element of array `X`.  `reshape` and `transpose` affect how it handles the elements of `X`, but do nothing internally to those elements.  Your change to `dtype` changes, not only the interpretation of the bytes in an element, but its size.  So there's no way of reusing the original `X` data buffer.

`numpy.lib.recfunctions` has a bunch of untility functions for working with rec arrays and structured arrays, including things like adding fields.  The ones that I've examined end copying data field by field from old to new - and recursively working its way down nested dtypes if needed.  But your resizing may go beyond its ability.

```
In [92]: X1=np.zeros(1,dtype=type2)

In [93]: X2=np.zeros(1,dtype=desired_type)

In [94]: X1.itemsize
Out[94]: 152

In [95]: X2.itemsize
Out[95]: 312
```

---

As for changing an existing `dtype`, you could edit its `descr`, and create a new `dtype`.  The main complication is that the `descr` is a mix of lists and tuples.  Lists are mutable, tuples are not. But here's a sample session:

Field names, at least at the top level, can be changed directly:

```
In [141]: type2.names=['column','description']
In [142]: type2
Out[142]: dtype([('column', [('col1', '<i4', (2,)), ('col2', '<i4', (4,))], (5,)), ('description', 'S32')])
```

Grab the `descr`, a list representation of the `dtype`:

```
In [164]: d2=type2.descr    
In [165]: d2
Out[165]: 
[('column', [('col1', '<i4', (2,)), ('col2', '<i4', (4,))], (5,)),
 ('description', '|S32')]

...
```

`d2` has enough information to recreate the dtype: `np.dtype(d2)`.

`d2` is a list of tuples; to modify any of those I need to convert it to a list:

```
In [168]: dd2=list(d2[0])
In [169]: dd2
Out[169]: ['column', [('col1', '<i4', (2,)), ('col2', '<i4', (4,))], (5,)]
```

Embedded in `dd2` is another tuple that we want to change:

```
In [174]: ddd2=list(dd2[1][0])
In [175]: ddd2
Out[175]: ['col1', '<i4', (2,)]

In [176]: ddd2[2]=(10,)    # change the list    
In [177]: ddd2
Out[177]: ['col1', '<i4', (10,)]
```

Write this list (converted back to tuple) to `dd2`:

```
In [181]: dd2[1][0]=tuple(ddd2)    
In [182]: dd2
Out[182]: ['column', [('col1', '<i4', (10,)), ('col2', '<i4', (4,))], (5,)]
```

Lo and behold, I ended up changing `d2` as well.  That's because what I changed in `[181]` was a list nested inside a tuple.  I probably didn't need to make `dd2` a list in the first place.  I was just using it as a way to reference that inner mutable list.

I can now use `d2` to make a dtype that matches `desired_dtype`.

```
In [183]: d2
Out[183]: 
[('column', [('col1', '<i4', (10,)), ('col2', '<i4', (4,))], (5,)),
 ('description', '|S32')]

In [184]: np.dtype(d2)
Out[184]: dtype([('column', [('col1', '<i4', (10,)), ('col2', '<i4', (4,))], (5,)), ('description', 'S32')])

In [185]: desired_type
Out[185]: dtype([('col', [('col1', '<i4', (10,)), ('col2', '<i4', (4,))], (5,)), ('descr', 'S32')])
```

Sorry if this is a bit long winded, but I think the exploration process is more important than the final result.

Comment: I left the logic out for the resizing because it wasn't really germane to my question. The answer you give isn't really what I am looking for. Many of the data types with which I am dealing, are very large and complex and defining them by hand as I did for `desired_type` is not really feasible. I want to be able to preserve the same exact structure minus the field I actually want to change.

Comment: So your focus is on manipulating a drupe object?  The input to `np.dtype` is normal Python - lists, tuples, dictionaries.  You can build those programatically.  The list and dictionary parts are mutable. I know you can change the field names of existing dtype objects.  I don't know about other parts.  I'd have to play around with a dtype in an Ipython session.

Comment: I've added a demonstration on how your `type2` can be modified to produce a new dtype that matches your `desire_type`.